# Insert happening when UPDATE is called in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, sql-update, prepared-statement, sql-insert

Sorry for my stupidity, but I have something strange happening here.  I am working on a DB2 database for an AS/400 and writing some SQL using some prepared statements in java.  I am pulling 49828 test records as of right now.  When I run the pstate.executeUpdate(), effectively it is returning '2' for each time the executeUpdate() is running.  Not sure why exactly.

Here's the method:

```
private void loadBenefitsAndDividendsData() {
    PreparedStatement pstate;
    String benefitTableName = "PFCASBENE";
    String dividendTableName = "PFCASDVACM";

    String sqlSelect = "SELECT "+ benefitTableName + ".FPLAN, " + 
        benefitTableName + ".FPSFLG, " + benefitTableName + 
        ".FPLAMT, " + benefitTableName + ".FUNITS, " + 
        dividendTableName + ".DAPAMT, " + otherSchema + "." + 
        dailyTableName + ".DBPOLN FROM " + benefitTableName + 
        " INNER JOIN " + dividendTableName + 
        " ON " + benefitTableName + ".FPOLNO = " + dividendTableName + 
        ".DAPOLN" + 
        " INNER JOIN " + otherSchema + "." + dailyTableName + 
        " ON " + dividendTableName + ".DAPOLN = " + 
        otherSchema + "." + dailyTableName + ".DBPOLN"; 

    String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE " + otherSchema + "." + dailyTableName + 
        " SET DBAPLN = ?, DBASTA = ?, DBAFAC = ?, DBAUNI = ? , DBAPUA = ? WHERE DBPOLN = ?";

    String policyNumber,dbapln, dbasta;
    BigDecimal dbauni,dbafac, dbapua;

    try {
        pstate = dataDataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
        ResultSet rSet = dataDataSource.getConnection().
            prepareStatement(sqlSelect).executeQuery();
        int count = 0;
        while (rSet.next()) {

            policyNumber = rSet.getString("DBPOLN");
            dbapln = rSet.getString("FPLAN");
            dbasta = rSet.getString("FPSFLG");
            dbafac = rSet.getBigDecimal("FPLAMT");
            dbauni = rSet.getBigDecimal("FUNITS");
            dbapua = rSet.getBigDecimal("DAPAMT");

            pstate.setString(1, dbapln);
            pstate.setString(2, dbasta);
            pstate.setBigDecimal(3, dbafac);
            pstate.setBigDecimal(4, dbauni);
            pstate.setBigDecimal(5,dbapua);
            pstate.setString(6, policyNumber);

            count += pstate.executeUpdate();
        }

        rSet.getStatement().close();
        pstate.close();

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        logger.error("SQLException was thrown:  " + sqlEx);
    }
    logger.info(getClass().getName() + "Has successfully loaded the PFCASBENE fields into DAILY01.");
}
```

When I attach my debugger and follow "count", it increments by two each time.  When I do an initial count on the table records, I am getting the correct amount which is 49828, after the update, I am getting 99656 which is exacly double, which points to the update statement is actually inserting rows.

The String sqlSelect returns 3 tables of data with 2 inner joins and I am getting the correct results.

The sqlUpdate is simply taking the ResultSet of the 3 joins and pushing them into the prepared statement, which updates the 49828 records with the data in the resultset.

I'm not exactly sure why this is inserting and twice at that and not simply updating.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks in advance,

Warmest Regards,

Josh

Comment: Any triggers that might be firing?

Comment: @JonSkeet No there are absolutely no triggers firing in this. It is a straight SQL PrepStmt call.  The dataDataSource is a Spring / Hibernate config, however, this is only doing this with this single statement.  The others, I am all doing are straight inserts.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  dang right, deleted completely retarded "friday afternoon" comment.

Comment: Is `DBPOLN` a unique key? Have you verified that you have 49828 unique values for `policyNumber` in your loop? (use a `Set` to accumulate them)

Comment: Also: are there any `IDENTITY` columns in the table?

Comment: @parsifal yes DBPOLN is a unique key. In my loop no, I've verified it via a query on the system however. The DB2 system will not allow two of the same DBPOLN's fields in the same column.  I swear this has got to be a logic error in my code.  The ResultSet criteria for the two inner joins are the dbpoln in the three tables have to match up.  So the only data I get is the data where all 3 dbpoln fields are the same.

Comment: @parsifal no, there are only character and numeric columns in the table

Comment: In *this* code, there doesn't appear to be a logic error; it's just too simple. If you have 49828 rows being returned from the resultset, and a unique key that guarantees one row per DBPOLN, and no  triggers that do something sneaky, then there's no way that you can get 99656 rows after the loop. So one of those three assumptions must be wrong. I think that keeping track of the DBPOLN values from the query, and comparing them to the post-loop values in the table is probably the best avenue of investigation.

Comment: @parsifal, just double checked. No triggers, and guarenteed 49828 unique rows. I'll step through a set number and see what exactly is going on again. 'Tis a total mystery. The ONLY thing I can see happening here is that the AS/400 is putting file locks on the database table (which is a normal AS/400 operation when someone is in the file), but it appears that when the Insert is complete, it is not releasing the lock on the table. From what I found here: http://archive.midrange.com/java400-l/201103/msg00060.html, it might point to unclosed resources in other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that my initial hunch was right that there was some open resources that were putting a file lock on the as/400 data file (DB2).  Despite my best attempts to be cute and fancy, simply re-writing the caller methods to my straight sql statements, propved to be the best (and fastest) way to tackle the solution.